# Add tableview to scrollview and have scrollview keep growing in height as cells are added to tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I want to make a full screen scrollview with various views in it but also have a tableview in it.

The thing is, I don't want the tableview to "reuse" views.

I am using auto-layout.

People keep asking why. Here is why:

**I want the scrollview to keep growing in height as cells are added to the tableview.** (using storyboard) This is something I want to do. Stop "suggesting" a "better" way because I know the "better" way. I am asking for **this** way.

For example:

[image]

As cells are added to the tableview, the entire scrollview keeps growing.

Comment: Why do you not want to reuse the cells?

Comment: tableview makes this UI easy to implement and you remove that component from the option.

Comment: Can you use table view with different TableViewCell 
AND
if custom views are at top and bottom than you can add Header footer to TableView

Comment: give height to tablview and upadate the height of tablview using contentsize's height property

Comment: Why do you want to use scrollView? If you want to use scrollview and dont want to resuse Tableview cells. Better use ScrollView without tableview cells

Comment: Well my viewcontroller is a bit complicated with many views in it. I want just one small tableview with a list of items I can move around and rearrange that are all visible all the time.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri Read the sentence right after I ask the question... -.-

Comment: @Micro i read it and it made no sense. So i'm asking you again, why do you not want to reuse the cells? Why do you want your scrollview to grow?

Comment: Another option... put your top 3 views in a table header view, and the bottom two views in a table footer view. Then just use a normal table view with reusable cells instead of embedding it in a scroll view.

Comment: @DonMag I. do. not. want. to. use. a. table. header. view. R-E-A-D my question and answer it if you have an answer or move on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are using autolayout, considering this i guess you already added constraint from the bottom of `tableview` to the `uiview` below it and also add a `height constraint` to the `tableview`. Make a `IBOutlet` of this height constraint. now write a method that would calculate the height depending on number of items you have to show for the tableview like

```
func calculateTableViewHeight() {
   heightConstraint.constant = YOUR_CELL_HEIGHT * NO_OF_ROWS
}
```

Call this method after `tableview.reloadData()`. And also don't for get to set the `scrolling for the tableview` to `false`

Comment: I like it so far